# Error: @"Bridge module %@ does not conform to RCTBridgeModule"

Tags: objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm new in React Native and I would like to use native modules in order to get a battery status of the phone. The problem is that I'm getting fallowing error: @"Bridge module `%@` does not conform to RCTBridgeModule". I'm guessing that it is class related but I'm not familiar with a Objective-C syntax. **I would really appreciate any help on this field even though the answer is simple. Thank you!**

**My BatteryStatus.h looks like this:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface BatteryStatus : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

**My BatteryStatus.m looks like this:**

```
#import "BatteryStatus.h"

@implementation BatteryStatus
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(BatteryStatus)

- (instancetype)init
{
  if ((self = [super init])) {

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

  }
  return self;
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(hide) {
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(updateBatteryLevel:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  callback(@[[self getBatteryStatus]]);
}

//manually get battery status by calling following method

-(NSDictionary*)getBatteryStatus
{

  float batteryLevel = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel;

  NSObject* currentLevel = nil;

  currentLevel = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(batteryLevel * 100)];

  NSMutableDictionary* batteryData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

  [batteryData setObject:currentLevel forKey:@"level"];
  return batteryData;

}

@end
```

**And I'm trying to use it in React Native like this:**

```
import { Text, View, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    batteryLevel: null,
    };
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     NativeModules.BatteryStatus.updateBatteryLevel((info) => {
     console.log(info.level);
     const level = Math.ceil(info.level);
     this.setState({ batteryLevel: level });
     });
   }
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>TEST</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you're not supposed to be inheriting from `RCTEventEmitter`. You only need to do so if you want to send events from a native module to JS which listens to specific events of your module; in this case you'll need to implement the `supportedEvents` method in your native module and specify the names of the events that you support. **You're getting this exception since you didn't implement this method.**

Since you're not sending any events, `BatteryStatus` should just inherit from the basic `NSObject` class like so:

```
@interface BatteryStatus : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

I recommend that you check out the RN guide for creating [native ios modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html).

Comment: You are right! Thank you for that. I will certainly check out the RN guide but first need to learn more RN itself without Objective-C.  Thank you anyway, it helped a lot!

Comment: Hello Artal, if I want class in module native has: listener and method which javascript side call, what should I do? I am searching the resolve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vannguyen in case you want to send event from native to JS, your class needs to inherit from `RCTEventEmitter`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I mean I have a module inherit from RCTEventEmitter. In javascript side, when componentDidMount and componentWillUnMount, I call add Listener and remove Listener. 
@interface DeeplinkManager : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>
- I want: in javascript side, I want call a method of DeepLinkManager. Ex: DeepLinkManager.functionA();
I tried add functionA(), but its error: functionA() is not define...
Thank you so much.

Comment: @vannguyen it's hard to tell, and it's a different issue than what's mentioned in this question. If you still need help I recommend that you ask a new question and add the code which you can't get to work

Comment: Hi Artal, I have just post a question. Please help me this issue. Thank you in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403549/exc-bad-access-when-get-value-of-static-nsstring-varible-in-class-inheritit-rcte