# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when get value of static NSString varible in class inheritit RCTEventEmitter

Tags: objective-c, react-native, variables, nsdictionary, native-module

I am building react native using native module. 
In the javascript side, I want to create native module on iOS for listener event and call some method from javascript side.
I have a static NSDictionary variable in Objective C. But when I get value of variable, it show EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I am building react native using native module. 
In the javascript side, I want to create native module on iOS for listener event and call some method from javascript side.
Here is my code

```
DeepLinkController.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, Linking, View, NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter} from 'react-native'
const DeeplinkManager = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.DeeplinkManager);
const TestMethod = NativeModules.TestMethod;

class DeepLinkController extends Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    TestMethod.notifyAppMount();
    DeeplinkManager.addListener('DeepLink', this.handleDeepLink);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    TestMethod.notifyAppUnMount();
    DeeplinkManager.removeListener('DeepLink', this.handleDeepLink);
  }

  handleDeepLink = (event) => {
    //navigate url
  }

  render(){
  }
}
```

In Objective-C, I create: DeeplinkManager.h, DeeplinkManager.m, TestMethod.h, TestMethod.m

```
DeeplinkManager.h
#if __has_include("RCTEventEmitter.h")
#import "RCTEventEmitter.h"
#else
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
#endif


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

static bool isAppMount = false, isNavigateNotitication = false;
static NSMutableDictionary<NSMutableString *, id> *resultTemp;


@interface DeeplinkManager : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

+ (void)notifyAppMount;
+ (void)notifyAppUnMount;
+ (void)emitEventWithDeeplink:(NSString *)deeplink andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END



#import "DeeplinkManager.h"

@implementation DeeplinkManager
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (void)startObserving
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(sendDeeplink:)
                                               name:@"Deeplink"
                                             object:nil];
}

- (void)stopObserving
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}


- (void)sendDeeplink:(NSNotification *)notifcation {
  NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *payload = @{@"deeplink": notifcation.userInfo[@"deeplink"],@"userInfo":notifcation.userInfo[@"userInfo"]};
  [self sendEventWithName:@"Deeplink" body:payload];
}

+ (void)emitEventWithDeeplink:(NSString *)deeplink andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload {
    isNavigateNotitication = true;
    resultTemp = @{@"deeplink": deeplink,@"userInfo":payload};
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getInitialDeeplink:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  reject:(__unused RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    //some code for handle get initial deeplink
}


+(void)notifyAppMount {
    NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *userInfo = resultTemp;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SMTDeeplink"
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
  }
}

+(void)notifyAppUnMount {
  isAppMount = false;
}

@end

---TestMethod.h
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
@interface TestMethod : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end

--- TestMethod.m
#import "TestMethod.h"
#import "DeeplinkManager.h"
@implementation TestMethod

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(notifyAppMount)
{
 [DeeplinkManager notifyAppMount];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(notifyAppUnMount)
{
  [DeeplinkManager notifyAppUnMount];
}
@end
```

When my app mounted, it call TestMethod.notifyAppMount. Then I push notification, it will set params into resultTemp variable. When I call TestMethod.notifyAppMount() when press button, this code show: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
+(void)notifyAppMount {
    NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *userInfo = resultTemp;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Deeplink"
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
  }
}
```

In javascriptside, I also can not call DeeplinkManager.getInitialDeeplink() although in deeplink module I declare method.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: at the moment it's very hard to help when your code has too many issues. For example: 1) `DeeplinkManager` has a `notifyAppMount` method in the header file and `notifyApp` method in the implementation file. 2) use of undeclared identifier `isAppMount1` 3) undeclared method `sendDeeplink`. Btw, this could be your crash issue if you're trying to call an undeclared method `notifyAppMount`

Comment: Hi Artal, I have just edit my code. For my case, when I receive a notification, it dispatch event "emitEventWithDeeplink", but now my app has not finished loading. So in the component javascript side, I add DeeplinkManager.notifyAppMount() to mark isAppMount Flag = true to trigger sendDeeplink again. I can set isAppMount, isNavigation variable, and get value of them. I can set value of resultTemp, but in function notifyAppMount in DeeplinkManager.m file, I receive: EXC_BAD_ACCESS for: static NSMutableDictionary<NSMutableString *, id> *resultTemp;